# Should I maintain my status quo in Poland or move right now?

Tags: study

I came in Poland last month. I am studying MSc in a Technical university in Poland. I have an ambition also to do a PhD here. Here, living cost and tuition fee is affordable. So affordable that, it looks like a poor country. There are many homeless people everywhere in the streets. One, thing is very shocking: the university teachers get a very low salary, around 3000 PLN.

In the mean time, I got an MSc admission offer from Liechtenstein. They will charge a very low tuition fee. But, I found that the living expense is very high. So, I will need to do a part-time job to cover my living expenses.

Is Liechtenstein a good place to move? Will I find job?

If I have an ambition to stay in the academia, what should be the country I choose to study? Should I complete my study and then try to move or should I move right now?

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately as we're still in beta, posts that are overly broad and subjective tend to get closed, as per our [help].  If you can edit and narrow your focus to an objectively answereable question, we'd be happy to try and help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_B._Calhoun#Norway_rat_experiments

Comment: Liechtenstein is a very peculiar country, you might want to research it a bit more before moving there. If you can move there that is, as housing and the number of foreigners residing in the country is such a sensitive issue that getting a residence permit might simply be impossible. They only issue a [grand total of 89 *per year*](http://www.liechtenstein-business.li/en/living-in-liechtenstein/life-in-the-principality/residence-permits/) and many employers invite expats to move to neighbouring Switzerland and commute every day because they cannot hire qualified workers any other way.